# Examples of PIDs and prime ideals

Tags: proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

(a) Give a specific example of a PID with exactly two prime ideals. Give a brief proof of your answer.

(b) Give an specific example of a PID with infinitely many prime ideals. Give a brief proof of your answer.

My ideas:

(a) $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$: localize $\mathbb Z$ at prime ideal p so $0_{(p)} \subset (p)_{(p)}$

A PID has $0$ and one other maximal ideal so it is a quasilocal PID

Is this a correct example and how should I 'give a brief proof'??

(b) $\mathbb Z$: only has $1$ and $-1$ as units and PID's are $1$-dimensional so only $0$ and minimal ideal exist

Proof Idea: Suppose $p_1...p_n$ are all positive primes. Then $p_1...p_{n+1}$ is not divisible by any prime $p_i$ so it is a unit which is a contradiction.

Any feedback or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: $(a)$ $\mathbb{Q}$ and $(b)$, $\mathbb{Z}$. For $(b)$, we have infinitely many primes ideals $p\mathbb{Z}$, $p\in \mathbb{P}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $\Bbb Q$ is not an example. $\Bbb Q$ is a field; it has one only maximal ideal, not two. The example $\Bbb Z_p$ of the OP is correct.